# How was this logo constructed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How did all these shapes get the same width? It drives me crazy.

Are the circles drawn with a stroke?? Or is it two ellipses combined and then a compound path was created??

Is that (2) a rectangle? Or is it drawn with a pen tool??

I have tried by taking the same pt/inch/mm in stroke but in vain. Could not even go near it.

No way I could match the width of the ellipse and rectangle. I have tried with stroke panel and with the transform panel.

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply set the stroke weights the same for an ellipses and a line. Don't use a "rectangle" anywhere.

[image]

Then select all and use `Object > Expand` to create shapes, then use the **Shape Builder tool** to merge/remove portions as necessary.

[image]

Comment: you are an angel <3 <3 <3

Comment: dont forget to get rid of unnecessary anchor points - thats always best practice!